# True or False: Constrained Optimization about Information Entropy

Tags: optimization, entropy, monotone-functions

Given Integer $N,M$ with $1\leq M\leq N$, consider the following optimization problem w.r.t $P = (p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_{N+M})$

Constraints：
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N+M} -p_k\log_2p_k-(1-p_k)\log_2(1-p_k) \geq N,\\\forall 1\leq k\leq N+M,\ 0\leq p_k\leq 0.5\\ 
$$
$$Minimize：\sum_{k=1}^{N+M} p_k(1-p_k)$$
We define $0\log_2 0 = 0$.

True or false:

**The optimal $P^*$ that minimize the objective function will have all coordinates equal. i.e.**

$P^* = (p,p,p,\cdots,p)$

---

My thoughts:

By intuition, the conjecture is true by symmetry.

I found both $F(p)=-p\log_2 p -(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ and $G(p)=p(1-p)$ are monotonic and concave in range$[0,0.5]$. But I can not make any more progress from it.

I examined the case N=1, M=1; and N=2, M=1, and found the conjecture is true for both cases.

Comment: @Ali I tried. But I got stuck on proving (1-2x)/log((1-x)/x) is bijective on [0,0.5].

Answer (score 1):

For a convex problem, one way to demonstrate the optimality of a solution is via the KKT conditions. Such a problem would be
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{minimise}&\quad&\sum_{k}g\left(y_{k}\right)\\
\text{subject to}&\quad&N-\sum_{k}f\left(y_{k}\right)\le 0
\end{eqnarray}
with $g$ convex and $f$ concave.

By your definition $G$ is not a convex function. But we may construct
$g$ convex (actually affine) by setting $g\left(z\right)=G\left(p\left(z\right)\right)$ with $p\left(z\right)=\left(1-\sqrt z\right)/2$. Then
$$ g\left(z\right)=\left(1-z\right)/4. $$
The Lagrangian
$$
L\left(y,\mu\right)=\sum_{k}g\left(y_{k}\right)+\left(N-\sum_{k}f\left(y_{k}\right)\right)\mu
$$
has derivative with respect to $y_{k}$
$$
L_{y_{k}}\left(y,\mu\right)=-\frac{1}{4}-\mu\,f'\left(y_{k}\right).
$$
To claim optimality it will suffice to exhibit  $\left(y,\mu\right)$ such that
$$
N-\sum_{k}f\left(y_{k}\right)=0
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mu\ge 0
\quad\text{and}\quad
-\frac{1}{4}-\mu\,f'\left(y_{k}\right)=0
\quad\text{for all }k.
$$
The first condition implies primal feasibility, the second dual feasibility, the first (again) complementary slackness and the third that the gradient of $L$ vanishes. The KKT conditions will have been satisfied.

Such a $\left(y,\mu\right)$ may be constructed with $y=\left(z,z,\ldots,z\right)$ and $\mu=-1/\left(4f'\left(z\right)\right)$ where we have $z$ satisfying
$$
f\left(z\right)=\frac{N}{N+M}
\quad\text{and}\quad
f'\left(z\right)<0.
$$
Of course we define $f(z)=F\left(p\left(z\right)\right)$. So
$$
  f(z)=
  1-\frac{\left(1-\sqrt z\right)
\ln\left(1-\sqrt z\right)
  +\left(1+\sqrt z\right)
\ln\left(1+\sqrt z\right)}
{2\ln 2}
$$
$$
  f'(z)=
-\frac{\ln\left(1+\sqrt z\right)-\ln\left(1-\sqrt z\right)}{\left(4\ln 2\right)\sqrt{z}}
=
-\frac{\text{arctanh}\sqrt z}{\left(2\ln 2\right)\sqrt{z}}
$$
$$
f''\left(z\right)=
\frac{\left(1-z\right)\text{arctanh} \sqrt z -\sqrt z}
{\left(4\ln 2\right)\left(1-z\right)z^{3/2}}.
$$
With domain $\left(0,1\right)$, $f$ has range $\left(0,1\right)$. So $0<N/\left(N+M\right)<1$ implies some $z$ with $0<z<1$ satisfying $f\left(z\right)=N/\left(N+M\right)$. And clearly $f'\left(z\right)<0$.

It remains to show that $f$ is indeed concave, using its second derivative. Almost certainly there are neater ways to do it but here is mine.
For $x > 0$,
$$ 1 < \cosh x = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sinh x\right) $$
$$ x \text{ sech} x < x < \sinh x $$
$$ \left(1-\tanh^{2}x\right) x = x \text{ sech}^{2} x < \tanh x  $$
Since $0<z<1$ implies $z=\tanh^{2}x$ for some $x>0$,
$$ \left(1-z\right)\text{arctanh} \sqrt z < \sqrt z $$
$$ \frac{\left(1-z\right)\text{arctanh} \sqrt z -\sqrt z}
{\left(4\ln 2\right)\left(1-z\right)z^{3/2}}< 0. $$

The conjecture is true, but we needed the convexity to prove it. An appeal to symmetry is not enough.

Here are some plots about $f$. I have more confidence in these than I have in my algebraic manipulations!

[image]

Comment: I like the approach, but the 2nd derivative of $F$ is negative, so your inequality with the sum of squares doesn't work.

Comment: @TickaJules Thanks for the sign error catch. I think I've fixed it now.